# Reading stored data in offline mode

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

In the last 2 days,I had a small problem. Let me explain the situation first. I get some data from my server(as JSON objects of course),store them in the database and display them in a recycler view.

Now I want to try something interesting. The data should be displayed when the Wifi is off. I thought that i wouldn't have any problem,as the data read from the sqlite database. But somehow I get nothing shown in my screen in that case.

Here is my code:

**AnnouncementsFragment**

```
public class AnnouncementsFragment extends Fragment {
public String titleForSQLite;
public String imageForSQLite;
public String articleForSQLite;
public static final String TAG = "AelApp";
private ArrayList<AnnouncementsModel> listItemsList;
private static final String IMAGE_URL = "http://www.theo-android.co.uk/ael/cms/announcement_images/";
AnnouncementsModel item;
RecyclerView myList;
AnnouncementsDatabaseHandler dba;
Context mContext;
private ArrayList<AnnouncementsModel> dbAnnouncements = new ArrayList<>();
private AnnouncementsAdapter announcementsAdapter;
public static final String ANNOUNCMENT_TAG = "ANNOUNCEMENT_FRAGMENT";
public AnnouncementsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    getActivity().setTitle("Ανακοινώσεις");

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_announcements, container, false);
    listItemsList = new ArrayList<>();


    dba = new AnnouncementsDatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    myList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_announcements);

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        myList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        announcementsAdapter = new AnnouncementsAdapter(getActivity(), listItemsList);
        myList.setAdapter(announcementsAdapter);


        updateAnnouncementsList();

        storingDataToSQlite();


    return rootView;
}


public void updateAnnouncementsList() {
    listItemsList.clear();


        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        JsonArrayRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL.GET_ANNOUNCEMENTS, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                //hidePD();

                // Parse json data.
                // Declare the json objects that we need and then for loop through the children array.
                // Do the json parse in a try catch block to catch the exceptions
                try {

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject post = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        item = new AnnouncementsModel();
                        item.setAnnouncement_title(post.getString("title"));
                        item.setAnnouncement_image(IMAGE_URL + post.getString("announcement_image"));
                        item.setAnnouncement_article(post.getString("article"));

                        listItemsList.add(item);

                        //Here I store the json strings.
                        titleForSQLite = post.getString("title");
                        imageForSQLite = post.getString("announcement_image");
                        articleForSQLite = post.getString("article");

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Update list by notifying the adapter of changes
                announcementsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                //hidePD();
            }
        });
        queue.add(jsObjRequest);

}
/*
* A method that add data in the SQlite database. It is found in AnnouncementsDatabaseHandler class
*/
public void storingDataToSQlite(){

    AnnouncementsModel myAnnouncements = new AnnouncementsModel();

    myAnnouncements.setAnnouncement_title(titleForSQLite);
    myAnnouncements.setAnnouncement_title(imageForSQLite);
    myAnnouncements.setAnnouncement_article(articleForSQLite);

    dba.addAnnouncements(myAnnouncements);
    fetchDataFromDB();
    dba.close();

}
/*
* A method that reads data from the database. It is found in AnnouncementsDatabaseHandler class
*/
public void fetchDataFromDB() {

    ArrayList<AnnouncementsModel> membersDB = dba.getAnnouncements();

    for(int i=0; i<membersDB.size();i++){
        String id = membersDB.get(i).getAnnouncement_id();
        String mTitle = membersDB.get(i).getAnnouncement_title();
        String mArticle = membersDB.get(i).getAnnouncement_article();

        String image = membersDB.get(i).getAnnouncement_image();

        AnnouncementsModel f = new AnnouncementsModel();

        f.setAnnouncement_id(id);
        f.setAnnouncement_title(mTitle);
        f.setAnnouncement_article(mArticle);
        f.setAnnouncement_image(image);

        dbAnnouncements.add(f);

    }
    dba.close();
  }
}
```

Inside my webservice method I pull the json strings from the response.(Maybe I should read the strings from the ArrayList instead?)

```
                        //Here I store the json strings.
                        titleForSQLite = post.getString("title");
                        imageForSQLite = post.getString("announcement_image");
                        articleForSQLite = post.getString("article");
```

Next I add titleForSQLite,imageForSQLite,articleForSQLite  in the database.

```
 public void storingDataToSQlite(){

    AnnouncementsModel myAnnouncements = new AnnouncementsModel();

    myAnnouncements.setAnnouncement_title(titleForSQLite);
    myAnnouncements.setAnnouncement_title(imageForSQLite);
    myAnnouncements.setAnnouncement_article(articleForSQLite);

    dba.addAnnouncements(myAnnouncements);
    fetchDataFromDB();
    dba.close();

}
```

and finally I read them

```
public void fetchDataFromDB() {

    ArrayList<AnnouncementsModel> membersDB = dba.getAnnouncements();

    for(int i=0; i<membersDB.size();i++){
        String id = membersDB.get(i).getAnnouncement_id();
        String mTitle = membersDB.get(i).getAnnouncement_title();
        String mArticle = membersDB.get(i).getAnnouncement_article();

        String image = membersDB.get(i).getAnnouncement_image();

        AnnouncementsModel f = new AnnouncementsModel();

        f.setAnnouncement_id(id);
        f.setAnnouncement_title(mTitle);
        f.setAnnouncement_article(mArticle);
        f.setAnnouncement_image(image);

        dbAnnouncements.add(f);

    }
    dba.close();
}
```

So why do I have the problem I described earlier? Since everything is stored in the database,data should read on both ON and OFF wifi case,right? Any ideas?

and this is my sqlite db code.

```
public class AnnouncementsDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private final ArrayList<AnnouncementsModel> announcementsModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public AnnouncementsDatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);
}
/*
* This callback method creates the database
*/
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_ANNOUNCEMENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + AnnouncementsConstants.TABLE_NAME +
            "(" + AnnouncementsConstants.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_TITLE+
            " TEXT, "  +  AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_image + " TEXT, " + AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_article + " TEXT);";



    db.execSQL(CREATE_ANNOUNCEMENTS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + AnnouncementsConstants.TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
}
/*
*Add contents to table. Those contents are json strings that
*are retrieved from the server!
*/
public void addAnnouncements(AnnouncementsModel announcementsModel) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(AnnouncementsConstants.KEY_ID,announcementsModel.getAnnouncement_id());
    values.put(AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_article, announcementsModel.getAnnouncement_title());
    values.put(AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_image, announcementsModel.getAnnouncement_title());
    values.put(AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_article, announcementsModel.getAnnouncement_article());


    db.insertWithOnConflict(AnnouncementsConstants.TABLE_NAME, AnnouncementsConstants.KEY_ID, values,
            SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    db.close();

    Log.d("Theo", "heeeey!data saved");
}
/*
* This method allows to read the stored data,and returns an
* array list.
*/
public ArrayList<AnnouncementsModel> getAnnouncements() {

    String select_query = "SELECT * " + AnnouncementsConstants.TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{
                    AnnouncementsConstants.KEY_ID, AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_TITLE, AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_article
            ,AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_image}, null, null, null, null,
            Constants.KEY_ID + " DESC");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            AnnouncementsModel m = new AnnouncementsModel();
            m.setAnnouncement_title(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_TITLE)));
            m.setAnnouncement_image(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_image)));
            m.setAnnouncement_article(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_article)));
            m.setAnnouncement_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AnnouncementsConstants.KEY_ID)));


            announcementsModelArrayList.add(m);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());


    }
    return announcementsModelArrayList;
}
```

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: how you checked that data is stored in your DB?..can you share the code you have written to store in db

Comment: yes the data are stored.

Comment: I put the code you asked,anyway.

Answer (score 1):

1. One issue is ,  titleForSQLite,imageForSQLite,articleForSQLite values are populated with only the last values in the data stream since they are inside a for loop.
2. Check whether your dba object is ready to read and write to database.

Comment: I was thinking what you are saying.But don't know how to proceed.

Comment: In your storingDataToSQlite() method you are storing only a single AnnouncementsModel object values. But you are parsing an arraylist from the json response and also fetching arraylist from the database. Why this?

Comment: Oh so I should store the whole Arraylist data inside the storingDataToSQlite() method,right?

Comment: Yes. Now you are storing only the last value.

Comment: Something like this?  AnnouncementsModel myAnnouncements = new AnnouncementsModel();

        listItemsList.add(myAnnouncements);

        dba.addAnnouncements(myAnnouncements);

        dba.close();

Comment: Change your addAnnouncements(AnnouncementsModel announcementsModel) method to addAnnouncements(ArrayList<AnnouncementsModel>). Include the insert logic inside a for loop.
Then remove storingDataToSQlite() from onCreate() and add immediately after parsing the values from json response.

This will solve your issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124639/discussion-between-theo-and-febi-mathew).

Comment: public void addAnnouncements(ArrayList<AnnouncementsModel> myArrayList) { 
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 

for(int i = 0;i<myArrayList.size();i++){ 

} 

Log.d("Theo", "heeeey!data saved"); 
}

Comment: how should I implement the for loop?

Comment: I did this: public void 
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        AnnouncementsModel model =...
        for(int i = 0;i<myArrayList.size();i++){
            ContentValues values...
            values.put(AnnouncementsConstants.KEY_ID,model.getAnnouncement_id());
            values.put(AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_article, model.getAnnouncement_title());
            ....
            db.insert(AnnouncementsConstants.TABLE_NAME,null,values);

            myArrayList.add(model);
        }

Answer (score 0):

I think your select query is wrong

It should be

```
String select_query = "SELECT * from " + AnnouncementsConstants.TABLE_NAME;
```

Call your below method form for loop after you receive the data from server

storingDataToSQlite();

And fetchDataFromDB(); after the for loop ends...or if the data is already there you can call this method from oncreate too

Add below code in Oncreate

```
if(isOnline)
{
  // get data from server
}else{
  // fetch data from db
}
```

Comment: I perform the query with Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{
                        AnnouncementsConstants.KEY_ID, AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_TITLE, AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_article
                ,AnnouncementsConstants.ANNOUNCEMENT_image}, null, null, null, null,
                Constants.KEY_ID + " DESC");

Comment: there was no need for the String select_query read operation.

Comment: It doesn't play any role for my problem.

Comment: //Here I store the json strings.
                            titleForSQLite = post.getString("title");
                            imageForSQLite = post.getString("announcement_image");
                            articleForSQLite = post.getString("article");

                            storingDataToSQlite();


                        }
                        fetchDataFromDB();

Comment: have you done debugging..what is the size of membersDB  list..and when you are getting list ..then you dnt need to again traverse through it...

Comment: the list size is 10 as the objects in my response. The recycler view is there when the wifi is on. But my guessing is that the titleForSQLite,imageForSQLite and articleForSQLite variables are tightly connected to the webservice. The webservice tries to run when the wifi is off. I get this error onErrorResponse: AelApp

Comment: So I should make the webservice  run only when the wifi on:)

Comment: Then I would need to check if there is an internet connection or not.